# Is there any ADB command to get the package name of 'default messaging app'?

Tags: sms, adb

Is there any ADB command to get the package name of 'default messaging app' ?

FYI,
below command is for getting the package name of the default launcher app.
"adb shell cmd shortcut get-default-launcher"

Answer (score 2):

`adb shell settings get secure sms_default_application`

Answer (score 1):

Did you try

`adb shell pm list packages -f`

Each line of the app list that is displayed will end in the app’s package name. For example, `package:/data/app/org.xbmc.kodi-1/base.apk=org.xbmc.kodi` is the line for Kodi. The package name should be descriptive enough for you to be able to pick out the app you’re looking for.

Comment: Thank you for your favor, but it is not the point of my question.
What I meant by it was that 'I want to get the "default SMS app's package name" by adb command.'

Answer (score 0):

You can also try

```
adb shell pm list packages -f | grep sms
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try

`adb shell cmd role get-role-holders android.app.role.SMS`